# Unable to get the errorlevel

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to find Admin Access in server ip's which are listed in serverslist.txt file.I am unable to catch the errorlevel because  for Admin and Not Admin cases the errorlevel is 0.
please help.

My code is :

```
set server=serverslist.txt
for /f %%a in (%server%) do(
psexec \\%%a -u user -p password net use | find "Administrator"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo "Admin Account for ", %%a >> admin.txt
)else (
echo "NOT Admin Account for ", %%a >> notadmin.txt
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set server=serverslist.txt
for /f %%a in (%server%) do (
 psexec \\%%a -u user -p password net use | find "Administrator"
 if errorlevel 1 (
  echo "NOT Admin Account for ", %%a >> notadmin.txt
 ) else (
  echo "Admin Account for ", %%a >> admin.txt
 )
)
```

The `IF ERRORLEVEL n` syntax responds to the `RUN-TIME` value of `ERRORLEVEL` and is true if `ERRORLEVEL` is `n` **OR GREATER THAN** `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a code block you need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `!variables!`:

```
if !errorlevel!==0
```